# Read google calendar date and title in node red

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, node-red

I'm building an application using raspberry pi and node red. I want to read all entries from  Google Callendar and then store then for further work.
I've install the node-red-node-google 0.1.0 and connect it to google api using Google Calendar. But it's not retrieving anything (dates or title) from the Calendar i specified in the config section.

[image: node red Google Calendar config]

It will be very helpful if someone has any idea how i can read entries in a Google Calendar and store them using mongodb or an array.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see your code.   Without seeing it we cant really help

Comment: I've not added any code. As i mention befor, i try to use node-red-node-google witch comes with google calendar and i set-it up to comunicate with my google api data. So i just added a calendar-node, and then set-it up and use the debug to see what comes out. But i got nothing and could not find anything that could help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with that node, it's is specifically for injecting messages into the flow a specific distance before that event starts.

You can look at the other Google API node

http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-google

Or look at accessing the API directly with the http nodes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried your method but can't figure out the error message: ` Error: Missing required parameters: calendarId, eventId ` And there is no place to add those. Any idea?

Comment: Pass the "calendarId" into the node as a json: {"calendarId" : "<your cal id goes here>"}  ... in my test, I have an inject node to inject this input into the "google" node. and it works.